# How are people handling AJAX posts to ActionMethods using [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

Seeing that the __RequestVerificationToken is not sent when using AJAX and [`ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateantiforgerytokenattribute.aspx) is looking for the token in Request.Form, how are people dealing with this problem.

I ended up doing this.

```
$("#regmember-form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var token = $('[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();

    alert($(this).attr('action'));

    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        data: { __RequestVerificationToken: token }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Very similar to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264904/how-are-people-handling-ajax-posts-to-actionmethods-using-validateantiforgerytok/7264919#7264919).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I grab the input off the page and send it back with the form post.  This assumes that you include it on the page in the first place.

```
 $('#somebutton').click( function() {
     var data = $('[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').serialize();
     $.post('/foo/bar', data, function(result) {
        // ...
     });
 });
```

Comment: I am using Ajax.BeginForm so I am going to have to grab $('#theform').submit trying this out will post back with results

Comment: it complains if I serialize by the way.

Comment: @CrazyCoderz - As long as the you have the token inside the form, I would think that it would *just work* using Ajax.BeginForm. That should send all the input in the form when it does its submission.  I was assuming you were submitting manually with only limited inputs. What error are you getting when you do the serialization?